# navbar-inverse CSS gradient///footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a footer with the same colour as navbar-inverse, but I can't figure out the actual CSS gradient. Is it possible to use navbar-inverse class to make a footer? Or the exact lines that create the gradient navbar-inverse uses?

Thank you!

Comment: use this to enter your values http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and click on "reverse" button.

Answer (score 1):

This is the css for the inverted navbar.

```
.footer {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#222222), to(#111111));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222222, #111111);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222, #111111);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #252525;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff222222', endColorstr='#ff111111', GradientType=0);
}
```

Comment: there are different inverted navbar styles that you shouldn't hard code any CSS by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I'm same problem, and this my working:

```
-----------------
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="">&copy; 2016 BNSON, Inc. | <a href="https://bnson.blogspot.com/">https://bnson.blogspot.com/</a></p>
    </div>
</footer>
------------------
```

and new CSS in .footer class:

```
-------------------
        .footer {
            padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #222;
            border-color: #080808;          
        }
------------------
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have the same problem and you'd like a resolution? Or does the code answer the question?